# Работа с удаленным проектом через гит

Tags: git, ssh

Есть проект битрикса на удаленном сервере,  к которому у меня есть доступ через FTP/SSH. Как я могу удаленно вносить изменения в проект через гит, а затем коммитить и пушить эти изменения и сохранять на сервере? Я использую PhpStorm и на локали не хочу копировать себе проект с сервера на локальный компьютер. Операционка на локали виндоус 11, на удаленном скорее всего линукс. Расскажите порядок действий в моем случае. Мне нужно создать, наверное, на гитлабе репозиторий и туда склонировать проект с сервера, а потом как вносить изменения? И как вводить команды git на удаленном сервере?

Comment: Почитайте документацию git, там есть вся информация.

Comment: В документации общие тезисы. Нет информации о том, как сохранить изменения в гите данные, если я правил на сервере в битриксе что-то, а потом хочу отметить это в коммите. Про phpStorm тоже нет описания, как можно не копируя на локальный компьютер проект работать с битриксом на удаленном сервере и контролировать все изменения, сохранять и актуализировать данные в гитлабе.

Comment: `git add .`, `git commit -m "Коммент"`, `git push` - для загрузки изменений с сервера в гит. `git pull` - для загрузки изменений из git на сервер. Вся эта информация есть в каком угодно виде (и не общими тезисами, а разжевана до мелочей). Это основы git.

Comment: "...как можно не копируя на локальный компьютер проект работать с битриксом на удаленном сервере и контролировать все изменения" - никак. Это же не FTP. Клонируете репозиторий на локалку (`git clone [ссылка]`), делаете что хотите, заливаете в git (или такие же команды, как на сервере в комменте выше, или через UI шторма). И на сервере сливаете по возможности изменения с локалки, которые прилетели в гит.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, спасибо за ответы. Команды вышеупомянутые вами я знаю, понимаю, что такое пушить проект или запуллить. А как же то, что на репозитории может быть лишь часть информации, так как в gitignor есть строки того, что ядро битрикса не копировать, какие-то папки не копировать. Как развернуть на локали полноценный битрикс проект клонируя, например, информацию из гитхаба или гитлаба репозитория?

Comment: Руками обычно, если это конфиги. Но локально обычно и не нужно что-то другое, вы же разрабатываете, а не боевой проект разворачиваете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не хотите копировать проект к себе на рабочий компьютер и у вас есть доступ по SSH, то можно использовать `SSHFS`: https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win

Это позволит вносить изменения непосредственно на удаленном сервере. Очевидный минус - это сетевые задержки.

В этом случае на сервере использовать удаленный гит-репозиторий будет необязательно, достаточно будет локального.